# Why does Google rich data snippet preview not display any rich data from my schema markup?

Tags: seo, microdata, markup

I'm trying to verify my schema.org implementation using Google rich data snippet preview, and am not sure if it's ok or not. [This is an example](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

It appears there are no errors, and it does recognize my implementation, but the preview doesn't include any rich data. For comparison, when I put a linkedin link, the preview comes up with [the rich data snippet](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://www.linkedin.com/in/jeresig):  (they have a "Brooklyn, New York - ‎Dean of Computer Science at Khan Academy" rich snippet placement for him as you can see in this picture:
[image]

What could be the reason my preview doesn't display any rich data?

Comment: You're not using the same Schema markup as LinkedIn, that is why the results are different.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Schema markup is displayed in rich snippets in search results and this is the case with the Schema you have implemented.

There is still value in marking up what you can on your website with relevant Schema though and for some websites, it is not always possible to have rich snippets displayed (depends on the type of content your website provides).

Maybe take a look at how LinkedIn markup People and Companies on their website and [what data is used in rich snippets](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=https://www.linkedin.com/in/zigojacko).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on "depends on the type of content your website provides"? I tried finding Linkedin's implementation in their page source, but didn't identify it.

Comment: In other words, [these](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) are the only types of content that can be marked up. Linkedin are using `hcard` and `hcalendar` which is a microformat markup type and you can learn how to implement [here](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is not yet support for Person in rich snippets, but there is support for authorship – which will provide your snippet with rich info.

If authorship is something you can use, provide a backlink to your Google+ profile page on your site like this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/01234567890? rel=author">My G+ page</a>
```

where *01234567890* is your Google Plus ID.

Further explained here: https://plus.google.com/authorship

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added the example of which rich snippets is shown for linkedin. Are these not "Person"? Should I implement it differently?

Comment: Spec for People Rich Snippets here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146646?hl=en

Comment: Yes, you are ofvourse right about that: there is a spec for People. How ever; People-coded content is not implemented in search results. Thats is why I suggest Noam uses author (publisher) instead, with the result of rich snippet – if this makes sense on Noams page.